# Is there a term for use of "would" conditional to indicate lack of precision?

Tags: conditionals, dialects, would

In the Northern Irish dialect, a speaker can say

> You see, I would have been very shy, and his encouragement really
> helped me.

Here, the "would have been" is used to indicate that the speaker is recalling a general state of being from the past, rather than any sort of conditional. It's used as a rhetorical device to encourage the listener to imagine a situational context. An alternative rendering of the same might be "Back then, I tended to be a very shy person, and his encouragement really helped me."

Is the use of "would have" a known language device? Does it have a formal term?

Comment: This seems to be a common feature, and it's not really a conditional unless you assume a hidden "if clause" - If I remember correctly... but that is not needed. The "would" is used to express a continuing state in the past. -- Consider "I would have been 15 when I had my first real girlfriend."

Comment: I think you're mistakenly assigning a genuine element of "uncertainty" to the usage in your examples. A more accurate alternative rendering would be *Back then, I **was** a very shy person* (the fact that speaker said ***would have been*** doesn't particularly imply *would **probably** have been* or ***might** have been*).

Comment: Whatever - I'd say such use of ***would have been*** instead of ***was*** is [often, *deferential*] ***circumlocution***.

Comment: Isn't this just the [subjunctive mood](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm)? Used to express hypotheticals, etc.

Comment: @jaredad7 No, it is not a subjunctive use. Neither is it conditional. It’s an epistemic modal of probability used in a backshifted perfect form. *He will have seen the movie already* is the non-backshifted version of this construction. The speaker is expressing their certainty about a past event.

Comment: It's not a conditional at all. It's just one more idiomatic use of the modal auxiliary _would_. All modals participate in many idioms and constructions. They're very busy verbs.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment Greybeard answered:

> This seems to be a common feature, and it's not really a conditional unless you assume a hidden "if clause" - If I remember correctly... but that is not needed. The "would" is used to express a continuing state in the past. -- Consider "I would have been 15 when I had my first real girlfriend."

Comment: Yes the "I would have been 15" implies thinking back to recall something as a  feature of the statement. I was just asking if there's a name.for this idiom. Quite probably the answer is "no"

Comment: @PoundHash  THEY ARE NOT MY ANSWERS. They're from the Community, who didn't put them where they were supposed to go. Should I just delete all comments and answers? Is that your request? I can delete them all then lock it forever from comments. Then people will have to answer. But they won't. And no answer will ever be given.

Comment: @PoundHash Then I'll disassociate my name with these posts and you'll never know who did it. The problem is that NOBODY POSTS ANSWERS. They put their answers in comments, and go away. Please go nag the people causing this problem by answering in comments. You know who they are. And also go nag the people who posts neither.

Comment: @PoundHash That's your opinion, and you're welcome to it because I do not share it. I fully intend to continue capturing the slackers' comments as answers, and it is senseless to limit that to only one slacker per question. Otherwise you make me judge which one I like best, and that's wrong. An answer is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment FumbleFingers answered:

> I think you're mistakenly assigning a genuine element of "uncertainty" to the usage in your examples. A more accurate alternative rendering would be *Back then, I **was** a very shy person* (the fact that speaker said ***would have been*** doesn't particularly imply *would **probably** have been* or ***might** have been*).

Comment: Consider my knuckles rapped! I wanted to take it a bit further and say something about using ***could*** rather than ***would*** to reflect genuine uncertainty on the part of the speaker, but *Back then I could have been very shy* sounds a bit weird (but *Back then I **could be** a bit shy* works fine). On the other hand, both versions of *Back then people **could / would** have thought I was very shy* work fine, and the choice of auxiliary *does* largely reflect ***might have / did***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you will be so kind as to write up a proper answer, I’d be glad to delete this post. Related to this are the narrative or habitual uses of *would* which are often forgotten by beginners, if not entirely unlearnt: *When I was a lad, we would have porridge each morning before dawn.*

Comment: The truth is I'm not *entirely* sure of my ground on this one. When I started writing my first comment under the question, I was fully intending to accompany it with a "migrate to ELL" closevote. But I started to doubt my position as I wrote the comment, so I decided to lie doggo and see what others had to say. Maybe *sometimes* "would" reflects the speaker's uncertainty regarding the truth of assertions, where *other times* it reflects speaker's wish to be "deferential / self-effacing / non-assertive".

Comment: I am from Northern Ireland and I'm pretty sure there's a softening of the certainty implied.